# D&D Turn Counter In Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I am trying to make a turn tracker/counter in google sheets. Here is some example data with character names and current turn.

```
Name      Turn
goblin      3
Skye        3
Molly       3
Greythorn   3
Miran       3
```

So the idea is that the person using the Sheet clicks a button and it updates the turn one by one as he clicks. So he has to click to update each turn individually. So in the example above I would click my "update turn" Button and the Goblin turn would change from 3 to 4 and then I would click the button again to update the next players turn from 3 to 4. That would happen for each player as I press the button and then it starts over after everyone has been done.

I do not know how to accomplish the goal of getting it to update each turn by 1 as I click the update turn button.

My idea and code played off the idea of creating an array and then each time the button is clicked it updates the numbers in the array individually and one at a time.

Here is the code I have built up so far. Its not crazy impressive as I am somewhat new to this.

```
function plusOne() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Combat');
  var Col="C"; //Column that will find the last row not empty, can be assigned as parameter
  var yourRange = sh.getRange(Col + 1).offset(sh.getLastRow()-1, 0); //+1 spare 1 row after last row
  var rsltRange = yourRange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);  
  var cVals = sh.getRange('C2:' + rsltRange.getA1Notation()).getValues();
  
  Logger.log(cVals);
 }
```

Right Now all this code does is build an array from the data in my Turn column which is "C" and prints the result to the log.

Here is an example of what it returns to the log.

```
[69.0, [3.0], [3.0], [3.0], [3.0]]
```

I hope this is more clear and better explains my goal. Thank you for all your help and Insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store each turn row and adjust values accordingly:

```
function plusOne() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Combat');
  const col = 3; //character column
  const maxTurns = 5;
  const startRow = 2;
  const lastRow = startRow + maxTurns - 1;
  const sProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const thisTurn = parseInt(sProps.getProperty('lastTurn') || (startRow-1)) + 1;
  const rgToPlusOne = sh.getRange(thisTurn, col + 1);
  rgToPlusOne.setValue(rgToPlusOne.getValue() + 1);
  sProps.setProperty(
    'lastTurn',
    String(thisTurn === lastRow ? startRow - 1 : thisTurn)
  );
}
```

Comment: That's Amazing! It woks almost perfectly. The only question I have is why does it not always start at the beginning/top of the column? Is there a way to set it to start at the top? I could make a refresh button that sets all turns back to 0 and sets the counter to start on top. Thoughts?

Comment: @Giles You can set the  starting row at `const startRow = 2;`. Kindly try to understand what each line does first before trying to implement a new feature.

Comment: I will do my best to make sure I know fully understand how it works before making any changes. or implementing new features.  I did have one last question. It isnt stopping at the bottom of my turn column. its just iterating down the entire column. Did I break something or is there any way to stop this?

Comment: @Giles I tested this now and it works as intended. Breaks after `maxTurns`(5) and continues at the top.

Answer (score 1):

> This should loop through all characters turns and then start over at the top until we finish and reset all turns to 0.

You are looking for a for loop, which lets you repeat a set of instructions until you reach some end condition. From what you wrote, it's not clear what truly constitutes "we finish," but if you can identify that condition, you can build a for loop around it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Here is a high-level approach without all the details:

```
for (let rounds = 0; AreRoundsOver(rounds); rounds++) {
  PerformAllTurns();
}

ResetTurns();
```

You would need one function:

```
function AreRoundsOver(int currentRound) {
  //return true when rounds are over, false when rounds should continue
}
```

And two methods (or a function that performs actions, but doesn't return anything):

```
function PerformAllTurns() {
  // go through each character/NPC and let them take their turns
}

function ResetTurns() {
  // reset all characters/NPCS turn to zero
}
```

Comment: So the idea is that the person using the Sheet clicks a button and it updates the turn 1 by 1 as he clicks. So he has to click to update each turn individually. "we finish" just means when the combat is over and we stop needing turns. From there we will reset the turn counter to 0 to get ready for any future fight. Does that help?

Comment: @Giles Please edit the question to clarify what you are looking for and where do you get stuck.